# Linux kernel function hooking fails in few cases?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver

I am writing a LKM that hooks a function with a custom function.
To achieve this I am modifying the function's prologue with

```
mov rax, <custom_func_addr>  // Intel syntax.
jmp rax
```

The exact opcode is : `"\x48\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xe0" // 8 '\x00' are replaced with actual address.`
The code works fine.say I hook vfs_read(), It works accordingly.

The is one case I have observed in which hooking fails :

```
void foo(char *func) {
    unsigned long addr = get_sym_addr(func);  // gets the address of function.
    DEBUG("function %s addr : %lu\n", func, addr);
    hook((void*)addr, &test_func_hooked);    // hook it with custom function.
    void (*test_func_orig) (int) = addr;     // get ptr to the function.
    test_func_orig(20);                      // call through func ptr.
    test_func(10);                           // call function directly.
}

//  defined in same file.
void test_func(int a) {
    printk("a = %d\n", a);
}
```

However Hooking happens properly when function gets called using func ptr.
and, If I directly call the function as - test_func(10), hook is not called.

Is there anything I am missing here ? I have tested the module by hooking vfs_read() , whenever a 'read' comes on any file, hook get called. Only this particular case where function to hook is in the same file, It is not working.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations? I'd use `objdump` to review the generated code but one thought I had is that `test_func(10);` was inlined and the `test_func` wrappers was effectively removed and a call to `printk` made directly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  No I am not using any compiling optimization. I will try to find some clue from objdump . thank you for help. I did not get the last part i.e test_func(10)  become inline ?

Comment: *If* the code is being optimized, an optimizer can place the contents of a function directly inside another function without the normal `call` `ret` mechanism. Such inlining can occur with optimizations on and when the function is in the same module (file) as the code that will use it.

Comment: One experiment you can try is this. Change `void test_func(int a) {` to `void __attribute__ ((noinline)) test_func(int a) {`